# Sending data without having to start a new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

So basically my question is just explained in the title. How can I send data between activities without having to start that activity which receive the data. Here's my code: This is the main activity sending the data :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mainedit1;
private TextView maintext1;
private Button   mainadd1;
private Button   maindone1;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
maindone1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.maindone);
mainedit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainedit1);
maintext1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.maintext1);
mainadd1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainadd);

    mainadd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           String test1= mainedit1.getText().toString();
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,test.class);
           intent.putExtra("word",test1);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And this is the activity receiving  the data :

```
public class test extends Activity {
TextView testtext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fortest);
    testtext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtext);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Word = intent.getStringExtra("word");
    testtext.setText(Word);
}
```

So what I did in here is to send the data but also starting the activity, and this is not what I want to share. Please show me how do I fix my code?

Comment: You could save the data to a file locally then read the data in the other Activity...why are u trying to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need an activity for that? Usually activities contains UI for users to interact with, if you need to do some operations in the background, you might be better off using a service.

Comment: And how do i do that ? What i want to do is sending that text inside the EditText to that other activity  .

Comment: Yes , i want the text to be shown in the second activity after it has been written in the first through the edittext. Like i want the Ui

Comment: Why can't you create a new activity and pass with `putExtra()` what is the limitation?

Comment: I dont want to start the other activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're just looking to save a string for later use. In your MainActivity, just do the following to save the string:

```
getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("word", test1).commit();
```

Then when you're ready to retrieve it in your test activity, just do so like this:

```
String Word = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("word", null);
testtext.setText(Word);
```

Comment: Excuse my stupidity but 'edit' is reading an error . Can you please write the whole thing ? i would be very thankful.

Comment: Thanks :) . And how can i retrieve the text that i saved in the mainactivity through sharedperefecnes in the test activity ?

Comment: That's the second part of my answer. You do this:
    getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("word", null);

Comment: Yeah yeah and how do i apply it to the textview ? 
Like in my example
`testtext.setText(what ?)`

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question

Comment: It worked . Thank you so much i appreciate it ! Let's be best friends :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedprefrence of android following code you can implement 
    In your MainActivity, just do the **following to save the string:**

```
getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("word", test1).commit();
```

**Then when you're ready to retrieve it in your test activity, just do so like this:**

```
String Word = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("word", null);
testtext.setText(Word);

                            OR
```

Sending data without having to start a new Acitivity, by create static variable
ex.

```
public class First_Activity extends Activity {
 public static String USER_FORMATED_NUMBER = null;

 USER_FORMATED_NUMBER="Data you want to pass"; 
}

public class Second_Activity extends Activity {
 String data=First_Activity.USER_FORMATED_NUMBER; 
}
```